# Trying to parameterize a connection, parameters not displaying

Tags: ssis

I am trying to parameterize a connection, but when I go to 'use existing parameter' none of my parameters are showing up (it is empty).

What is the reason for this?

Note:  This package was using package configuration before

**Steps:**

Right-click on one of connections in the 'connections managers' tab, select 'parameterize...'.  I then select the radio 'use existing parameter'.  The dropdown list is empty.

Comment: @billinkc I updated my question with the steps thanks!

Comment: what is the setup of the parameter that you have created, and I hope not to offend with this next question but are you confusing parameters with variables?